# Python package using multiple modules -- how to implement logging that's easy for user?

Tags: python, class, logging, module, package

## Original Question

I have a package, [qualysapi](https://github.com/paragbaxi/qualysapi/) which I have successfully implemented package-level logging, but I'm looking for module-level granularity transparent to the user. I modeled my implementation from this solution:

[Efficient way of setting Logging across a Package Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348958/efficient-way-of-setting-logging-across-a-package-module)

I am looking to implement package-level logging for a "user" module that leverages that class to add that logger. I believe that the user module should only have to add the package name and not have to know the modules that are contained within the package.

Below is what I have so far (simplified):

**package/____init____.py:**

```
from package_name.util import connect
```

**package/util.py:**

```
import logging
import package_name.module_class

logger = logging.getLogger(package_name)

def connect():
    return module_class.ClassName()
```

**package/module_class.py:**

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self):
        package_name.util.logger.info("Created instance.")
```

**user.py:**

```
import logging
import package_name

# My logging.
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# Log package_name.
logger_pkg = logging.getLogger('package_name')
logger.addHandler(logger_pkg)
# Define a Handler which writes to the sys.stderr.
logger_console = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(logger_console)
```

I'm interested to know best practices on maintaining the ease of use for the user while allowing for module-level package logging.

## Update 1

I'm doing it wrong. Changing question to what's supposed to happen.

How can I set up a package with multiple modules so that the user only has to add the package name for all logger handlers of all modules of that package? Example user module below:

```
import logging, package_name
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger_pkg = logging.getLogger('package_name')
logger.addHandler(logger_pkg)
```

Comment: I saw your comment. What do you mean by "add all the package loggers"? Normally, you can just add handlers to the root logger, set the levels of all loggers as you want (bearing in mind how effective levels are computed), and events from all loggers should be logged according to the levels which you set.

Comment: Vinay, updated question to clarify. I gave up on my methodology. This question is now in response to your answer.

Comment: What? You're calling `addHandler` with a *logger* as argument. Perhaps you should read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to follow what it says in the [logging tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial):

A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This means that logger names track the package/module hierarchy, and it’s intuitively obvious where events are logged just from the logger name.

You then do e.g.

```
logger.debug('Message with %d %s', 2, 'arguments')
```

throughout the module. The approach also allows users of your library to turn verbosity up / down for specific modules.

The approach you describe seems somewhat convoluted, but perhaps you have a good reason for doing it that way.

If there's some reason you can't adopt the approach given in the tutorial, do comment on this answer to let me know what it is.

Comment: I have read the tutorial and it makes practical sense. What I had trouble with is being able to add the all package modules to the "user" module without having to know all the module names. Is there a way to just add all the package's loggers easily?

Comment: This is also a great read: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/logging/